# symfony 4 twig, axios: How can I get form.widget value with axios

Tags: axios, twig, symfony4

I'm trying to get a form.widget value with axios so i can pass it in a url. i tried :

```
   const url = Routing.generate('route_name', {type: {{ formC.type.vars.value }});
```

but i get empty value.
Can anybody help?

Comment: Why do you use fosjsroutingbundle if you don't pass js variables?

Comment: i need to keep the same page with no refresh so i generated the url to the fn which i need and executed it :
```
 axios.get(url).then(function (response) {
                    window.alert("200")


                })
```